# Apache Felix Web Management Console deploy fails

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

Apache Felix Web Management Console deploy fails with Unsatisfied requirement(s). Here is the log:

```
$ java -jar bin/felix.jar
____________________________
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

g! repos list
http://incubator.apache.org/sling/obr/sling.xml
http://sling.apache.org/obr/repository.xml
http://incubator.apache.org/sling/obr/thirdparty.xml
http://felix.apache.org/obr/releases.xml
g! deploy -s "Apache Felix Web Management Console"
Unsatisfied requirement(s):
---------------------------
   (&(package=org.apache.commons.fileupload))
      Apache Felix Web Management Console
   (&(package=org.apache.commons.io))
      Apache Felix Web Management Console
   (&(package=org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet))
      Apache Felix Web Management Console
   (&(package=org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk))
      Apache Felix Web Management Console
   (&(package=org.json))
      Apache Felix Web Management Console
```

As per above I tried adding some other repositories to help with the resolution.

Any known workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this selects the "bare" version of the WebConsole which does not include various dependencies. You might want to try "org.apache.felix.webconsole" as the name to select the Web Console by the symbolic name.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. `list -v` this will give you more details on the bundle names; what you get when you use `list` is only the description of the bundle not it's symbolic name. In case of the "Apache Felix Web Management Console" the symbolic name is "org.apache.felix.webconsole"
2. `deploy org.apache.felix.webconsole` this will install the bundle with it's dependencies.
3. `lb` to check if everything went OK. You should see the new bundles installed.
4. Start the web console bundle and the HTTP Service bundle in order to be able to access the web console.
5. Point your browser to `http://localhost:8080/system/console/` and you will see the web console.